# ASP.Net MVC3 Populating Master Page Sections from UserControl/PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Pessimistic as to whether this is even possible, but what I'd like to do is populate a ContentPlaceholder on the Master Page from a User Control on the View.

More specifically, I would like to put a block in my master page like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="StartupScript" runat="server" />
    });
</script>
```

Then in my page, I add my user control like:

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl");%>
```

Then have MyUserControl put some javascript that it wants to run at startup into the StartupScript placeholder on the master page, like:

```
<div id="MyUserControl"></div>

<Content ID="StartupScriptContent" ContentPlaceholderID="StartupScript" runat="server">
    $("#MyUserControl").load(...);
</Content>
```

In case it isn't obvious, the javascript isn't the actual use case. In case anyone is curious, I'd like to initialize the DynaTree jQuery plugin when the DOM loads, only if the UserControl is on the p

Comment: Just to elaborate, I want to have this treeview be used on more than one Page/View. The DynaTree treeview control is created by placing a div and then calling a jQuery plugin on that div. So, I want to create a user control that is like <div id="mytree"></div> <script>$(document.ready(function () { $("#mytree").dynatree(/*lots of options, some set by the ViewData*/); });</script>. I want my User Controls to be self-contained, I don't want to put the HTML in the control and the JS in the Page/View. I expect to have more than one control like this, where there's markup and JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Control (including an ASCX partial in MVC) is simply rendered where ever you tell it to be rendered in the parent page/control markup.

So, if you want the output of a control to end up going into a `ContentPlaceholder`, wrap the tag for it in the page with the `Content` tag. But it's not valid to put `Content` tags directly in controls/partials.

I suspect there may be another way to do what you are thinking of, though; maybe someone else will have a brain fart regarding that, or maybe you could elaborate on why you need it.

Comment: This is correct. I will add, though, that I eventually just decided to make my control self contained by adding the javascript directly to the control using $(document).ready to make sure it fires after the item loads.